# Accessing a file in a different Java class?

Tags: java, file, class, jfilechooser

I retrieved a `file` using the `JFileChooser` in the main method of my java program. My question is how do I access this `file` in a different class within the same package of my program?

Comment: Either pass it to that other class (via constructor or some other method) or make it a static variable in your main java program and then other classes would be able to reference it

Comment: create an instance variable for that file/path and the relative getter

Comment: you guys should write those as answers, such that they can be accepted.

Comment: yes, but it's quite a generic answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes can communicate in different ways and choosing the right way depends on the specific case and the architecture. I would go with saving the file into a field in your class and create a getter for that field. Thanks to that you will be able to access the file in other classes.

So your classes could look something like that:

```
public class FileHolder {

    private File file;

    public File getFile() {
        return this.file;
    }

    private void retrieveFile() {
        // method which sets the file
    }

    // other methods and fields

 }
```

and

```
public class FileUser {

   private void doSomethingWithTheFile() {
        FileHolder fileHolder = new FileHolder();
        fileHolder.retrieveFile();
        File file = fileHolder.getFile();
        // use the file
    }

}
```